# How to exclude method in c# for sonarqube code coverage

Tags: c#, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube-scan

I am using sonarqube  for code coverage in visual studio c# project
I want to exclude some methods for the sonar sonarqube code coverage.
I have tried the ExcludeFromCodeCoverage attribute but this is not working.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried? [ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.excludefromcodecoverageattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) this attribute could be used at class level too

If not work, could be a problem in your Sonar Analyzer

Comment: I think, this is correct. wonder why its not marked as answer!